# Longtext data with "", :, {, [ is not getting inserted in the table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have created a table with 4 columns: id(int), startdate(varchar), enddate(varchar), and details(longtext). The details column contains around 3mb data with special characters &,@, [, {, ", ',:, etc. I tried to insert details into the table using the following query.

```
INSERT INTO Details(StartDate,EndDate,Details)VALUES('2020-07-26','2020-07-26', '{"ticket":[{"child":[{"id":1138240708591,"via":"Rule","via_reference_id":32826259,"status":"closed","rel":"automation","event_type":"Change","previous_value":"solved"}],"id":1138240708451,"ticket_id":767446,"timestamp":1595775911,"created_at":"2020-07-26T15:05:11Z","updater_id":-1,"via":"Rule","system":{"client":null,"location":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null},"metadata":{"system":{},"custom":{}},"event_type":"Audit"},{"child":[{"id":1138240713431,"via":"Rule","via_reference_id":32826259,"status":"closed","rel":"automation","event_type":"Change","previous_value":"solved"}],"id":1138240713351,"ticket_id":767444,"timestamp":1595775911,"created_at":"2020-07-26T15:05:11Z","updater_id":-1,"via":"Rule","system":{"client":null,"location":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null},"metadata":{"system":{},"custom":{}},"event_type":"Audit"}');
```

But the details are not inserting into the table. Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance

[Current table contents. Details columns are still empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FBIK.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: that is not reprocible see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99f383e85b52da4b10bed253f85cc9e4 could you show a example where the problem occurs. Besides don't save date as varchar and you could use json instead of LongTEXT, not with youir example that is invalid

Comment: @Joni I am not getting any error. But no data was not inserting into the table. not even the dates. I tried mysql_real_escape_string($Details) and I could able to see the dates in the table. But still, the Details column remains empty.

Comment: Updated the question with current table contents

Comment: Your reference to `mysql_real_escape_string()` suggests this is not the actual code. If you submit queries from PHP just make sure you're using bind parameters and prepared statements. It's simple and it works.